# python- sqlite3.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error"

Tags: python, sqlite

This isn't my code; I got it from https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC4KX0hatvRrOVy_D0nPlusg. The author didn't have the source code so I just had to type it up from the video. His worked fine but I kept getting this error:

```
File "D:\ProgramDevelopment\Python\Project\Python_GUI_IDEL\PythonDatabaseYoutube.py", line 45, in run_query
query_result= cursor.execute(query,parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error"
```

Link in github: https://github.com/ahmed-aya/Python_database/blob/master/Python_Database

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3

class Product(object):

  def __init__(self,wind):
    self.wind=wind
    self.wind.title('IT products')

    frame = LabelFrame (self.wind,text= 'Add new record')
    frame.grid (row=0,column=1)

    Label(frame,text='Name:').grid(row=1,column=1)
    self.name =Entry(frame)
    self.name.grid(row=1,column=2)

    Label(frame,text='Price:').grid(row=2,column=1)
    self.price =Entry(frame)
    self.price.grid(row=2,column=2)

    ttk.Button(frame,text='Add record',command=self.adding).grid(row=3,column=2)
    self.message=Label(text='',fg='red')
    self.message.grid(row=3,column=0)

    self.tree=ttk.Treeview(height=10,column=2)
    self.tree.grid(row=4,column=0,columnspan=2)
    self.tree.heading('#0',text='Name',anchor=W)
    self.tree.heading(2,text='Price',anchor=W)

    ttk.Button(text='Delete record',command=self.deleting).grid(row=5,column=0)
    ttk.Button(text='Edit record',command=self.editing).grid(row=5,column=1)

    self.viewing_records()

  def run_query (self, query, parameters=()):
    with sqlite3.connect('database.db') as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        query_result= cursor.execute(query,parameters)
        conn.commit()
    return query_result

  def viewing_records(self):
    records = self.tree.get_children()
    for element in records:
        self.tree.delete(element)
    query ='SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY name DESC'
    db_rows = self.run_query (query)
    for row in db_rows:
        self.tree.insert('',0,text=row[1], values = row[2])

  def validation (self):
    return len (self.name.get()) !=0 and len (self.price.get()) !=0

  def adding (self):
    if self.validation():
        query ='INSERT INTO product  VALUES (NULL,?,?)'
        parameters =(self.name.get(),self.price.get())
        self.run_query(query,parameters)
        self.message ['text'] = 'Record {} added'.format (self.name.get())
        self.name.delete(0,END)
        self.price.delete(0,END)
    else:
        self.message['text']='name field or price is empty'
    self.viewing_records()

  def deleting (self):
    self.message['text']=''
    try:
        self.tree.item (self.tree.selection())['text']
    except IndexError as e:
        self.message['text']='Please, select recoard'
        return

    self.message['text']=''
    name=self.tree.item (self.tree.selection())['text']
    query='DELETE FROM product WHERE name=?'
    self.run_query(query,(name,))
    self.message['text']='Record {} deleted.'.format(name)
    self.viewing_records()

  def editing(self):
    self.message['text']=""
    try:
        self.tree.item (self.tree.selection())['values'][0]
    except IndexError as e:
        self.message['text']='Please select record'
        return
    name = self.tree.item (self.tree.selection())['text']
    old_price = self.tree.item (self.tree.selection())['values'][0]

    self.edit_wind= Toplevel()
    self.edit_wind.title('Edit Window')

    Label (self.edit_wind,text='Old name: ').grid(row=0,column=1)
    Entry (self.edit_wind,textvariable=StringVar(self.edit_wind,value=name),state='readonly').grid(row=0,column=2)
    Label (self.edit_wind,text='New name: ').grid(row=1,column=1)
    new_name = Entry(self.edit_wind)
    new_name.grid(row=1,column=2)

    Label (self.edit_wind,text='Old price: ').grid(row=2,column=1)
    Entry (self.edit_wind,textvariable = DoubleVar(self.edit_wind,value=old_price),state='readonly').grid(row=2,column=2)
    Label (self.edit_wind,text='New price: ').grid(row=3,column=1)
    new_price=Entry(self.edit_wind)
    new_price.grid(row=3,column=2)

    Button(self.edit_wind,text='save changes', command=lambda:self.edit_records(new_name.get(),name,new_price.get(),old_price)).grid(row=4,column=2,sticky=W)
    self.edit_wind.mainloop()

  def edit_records(self, new_name,name,new_price,old_price):
    query = 'UPDATE product SET name=?,price,=? WHERE name=? AND price =?'
    parameters = (new_name,new_price,name,old_price)
    self.run_query (query,parameters)
    self.edit_wind.destroy()
    self.message['text']='Record {} changed.'.format(name)
    self.viewing_records()

if __name__== '__main__':
    wind=Tk()
    application = Product(wind)
    wind.mainloop()
```

Comment: `query = 'UPDATE product SET name=?,price,=? WHERE name=? AND price =?'` and `query ='INSERT INTO product  VALUES (NULL,?,?)'` seem to be the most likely culprits here.

Comment: @JacobIRR the def editing_records is where every the error comes up from. before that im good. since youre saying those are the issues how showed i change them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your error says, you have a typo.

```
query = 'UPDATE product SET name=?,price,=? WHERE name=? AND price =?'
                                        ^ extra comma here
```

Comment: you are my hero